# minify with raw bundler plugin in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Objective is to concatenate `src` files to create a library file, and then create another version that's minified with sources maps. I'm using [RawBundlerPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-raw-bundler).

Following works like a charm! What's missing is how to generate another minified library.

```
const path = require("path");
const RawBundlerPlugin = require("webpack-raw-bundler");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/header.txt",
    output: {
        filename: "MyLib.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.txt$/, use: "raw-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new RawBundlerPlugin({
            readEncoding: "utf-8",
            bundles: [ "MyLib.js" ],
            "MyLib.js": [
                "src/header.txt",
                "src/Product.js",
                "src/Customer.js",
                "src/copyright.txt"
            ]
        })
    ],
    mode: "none"
};
```

**Question**: How to include a minification build with sources maps using above configuration?

Or

maybe take the `dist/MyLib.js` and minify it to `dist/MyLib.min.js` through a subsequent process.

**attempt** https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
    })],
},
```